# Famous tongue-twister which is pronounced in parties

Tags: фонетика

I've heard from a stranger a tongue-twister, from which I understood not a single word. It's supposed to be a particularly difficult short Russian phrase which, I was told, it's pronounced mostly when people get drunk and they tend to say bad words when they fail to pronounce it correctly. Which is this phrase or tongue-twister?

Well, the actual question is:

*Which bad words emerge when it's pronounced?*

Comment: Прыжок с переподвыподвертом?

Comment: @Artemix это вопрос или это такая фраза?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe it was **Прыжок с переподвыподвертом** or (simpler case) **Прыжок с подвыподвертом**. This means something like "jump with body overtwist" ("подвыподверт" here comes from the words *подвернуть* and/or *вертеть*).

If one fails to pronounce the second word correctly, they have very high chance to say *подпердом*, *подвыпердом*, *переподвыпердом*. All these words are derived from the word *пердеть* - *to fart*) which replaces "body twist" to "farting", and the result is "jump with overfarting".

The word переподвыподверт is constructed using a bunch of prefixes:

> пере- под- вы- под- верт

The selection of the prefixes clearly shows that the main goal of this tongue-twister is to make the person that pronounces it to mix up initial "в" and "п".

Comment: My favourite one is "Еду я по выбоине, и из выбоины не выеду я". When drunk, people cannot pronouce it correctly, what they actually say sounds really funny. :D

Comment: @YellowSky This one is also nice, but mine was the shortest I could recall.

Comment: "Сиреневенький" - in one word or a word in the phrase. "Бесперспективняк" - it is difficult to articulate even sober.

Comment: @eugene Бесперспективняк is ok, but what about emerging bad words?

Comment: There are no bad words like "выверт/выперд" but it's funny when drunk man trying to pronounce it. It's just a short tongue twister.

Answer (score 4):

I know one tongue-twister which indeed produces bad words and is really difficult:
`Ох у ямы холм с кулями, выйду нá холм куль поправлю`

Answer (score 1):

The one that comes to my mind is "Себя от холода страхуя, купил доху я на меху [я]"